# I get ClassCast exception when I enumerate vector with String type parameter, but no exception is there with Integer as type parameter

Tags: java, generics, vector, enumeration

I was trying my hands on vectors and wrote a simple code to access its elements through enumeration.

```
Vector v = new Vector();
    v.add("Some String");
    v.add(10);

    Enumeration e = v.elements();
    while(e.hasMoreElements()) System.out.println(e.nextElement());
```

Working with raw types produces results as expected(prints the elements). But, when I use generic type of enumerator, it gets tricky.

With String as type parameter:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
    v.add("Some String");
    v.add(10);

    Enumeration<String> e = v.elements();
    while(e.hasMoreElements()) System.out.println(e.nextElement());
```

Output:

> Some String
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

With Integer as type parameter:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
    v.add("Some String");
    v.add(10);

    Enumeration<Integer> e = v.elements();
    while(e.hasMoreElements()) System.out.println(e.nextElement());
```

Output:

> Some String
>
> 10

What is happening here?
Shouldn't both the cases produce ClassCast exception?

Comment: `Enumeration<> e = v.elements();` How does this compile?

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov I think it's a typo and OP meant `Enumeration<String>`.

Comment: You're using `Vector` raw type: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/1608594 You shouldn't use raw types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that all generics are erased at compilation, it is just to help the compiler confirm you have made no mistakes. Probably you get several warnings at this points, saying you should not use raw types (raw means `Vector` instead of `Vector<String>` etc). The generics equivalent of a raw type is `<?>` indicating you will allow any type (note that that will cause you code not to compiler anymore).

The behavior you see is because there are two (actually several more, but in your case two are used) functions with the name `System.out.println()` and different parameter types, this is called (method overloading):

1. System.out.println(String)
2. System.out.println(Object)

At compile time it is decided which is called for your code.

In the String example the enumeration has generic type `String` and will call the first. However when it gets passed an `Integer` object from your `Vector`, this cause a failure when casting to it to String. 
So in this case, the compiler converts your code into the following (roughly):

```
Enumeration e = v.elements();
while(e.hasMoreElements()) System.out.println((String)e.nextElement());
```

In the Integer example the enumeration has generic type `Integer` which will map to `System.out.println(Object)`, which accepts both `String` and `Integer`, so all goes well.

On a sidenote: by default you should use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`, it has a much cleaner interface, due to legacy methods in `Vector`. Also `Vector` it is synchronized causing unneeded overhead.